# Juju status pending (focal is not a valid distro_series. It should be one of: ””, ”ubuntu/bionic”.”)

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm new with juju and trying to deploy OpenStack bundle with juju according to the canonical deployment guide
https://ubuntu.com/openstack/install#cluster-deployment.

But after `juju deploy cs:bundle/openstack-base`, I got this error:

[image: juju status]

[image: lxd status]

```
unexpected: ServerError: 400 Bad Request ({"distro_series": ["'focal' is not a valid distro_series.  It should be one of: '', 'ubuntu/bionic'."]})
```

Comment: While configuring MAAS, did you choose 18.04 instead of 20.04?

Comment: yes I used 18.04

Comment: Open configuration and try switching to 20.04.

Comment: can you specify which configuration?

Comment: Where you have selected the image.